# Why is MSpec reporting false positive when using Entity Framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework-4, mspec

I'm trying to write some Mspec tests against some EF4 objects. However they are returning false positives. I don't know if it is the way that I've written the tests or if there is something else going on. The test class is below:

```
[Subject(typeof (Product))]
public class When_loading_a_known_product 
{
    protected static Product product;
    protected static ProductDbContext dbContext;

    Establish context = () =>
    {
        dbContext = new ProductDbContext(ConnectionStringProvider.GetConnectionString(BusinessDomain.Product));
    };

    Because of = () =>
                     {
                         product = dbContext.Products.First(x => x.Id == 2688);
                     };

    // The next four tests should be false but all pass ( the actual count is 4 for the given record)
    It should_have_a_known_number_of_Classifications = () => product.Classifications.Count().Equals(9999);
    It should_have_a_known_number_of_Classifications2 = () => product.Classifications.Count().Equals(1);
    It should_have_a_known_number_of_Classifications3 = () => product.Classifications.Count().Equals(-99);
    It should_have_a_known_number_of_Classifications4 = () => product.Classifications.Count().Equals(4.5);
    //
}
```

The same tests written within Nunit work correctly.

```
[Test]
public void It_should_have_a_known_number_of_Classifications()
{
    private ProductDbContext dbContext = new ProductDbContext(ConnectionStringProvider.GetConnectionString(BusinessDomain.Product));;
    Product product = dbContext.Products.Find(2688);
    // true
    Assert.That(product.Classifications.Count(), Is.EqualTo(4));

    // All of these will correctly regester as false
    //Assert.That(product.Classifications.Count(), Is.EqualTo(9999));
    //Assert.That(product.Classifications.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
    //Assert.That(product.Classifications.Count(), Is.EqualTo(-99));
    //Assert.That(product.Classifications.Count(), Is.EqualTo(4.5));
}
```

Being fairly new to both EF4 and MSpec, I'm hoping someone can point out my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use MSpec's assertion library:

```
It should_have_a_known_number_of_Classifications =
  () => product.Classifications.Count().ShouldEqual(9999);
```

MSpec (and NUnit) identify test outcomes (successful, failing) based on if the code inside the framework's methods (`[Test]`, `It`) throws an exception. You use the .NET Framework's `object.Equals()` method to assert which just returns true or false. Therefore, MSpec considers your specifications as successful, because `Equals()` doesn't throw on inequality.

Comment: That what it was exactly. Thanks.